# oracle sql split text into columns based on each occurrence of a certain character set

Tags: sql, oracle

In our database (Oracle), there is a field named *CONVERSATION* containing speech to text records (formatted as CLOB).
After some pre-processing and replacement of unnecessary characters, currently this field has a format as the example below.

I want to split texts of agents and customers into separate columns. And I want them separeted by comma for each part starts with "a:" or "c:".
How can I do that?

"a:" stands for agent  and "c:" stands for customer

```
CREATE TABLE TEXT_RECORDS (
    CONVERSATION CLOB
    );

INSERT INTO TEXT_RECORDS
(CONVERSATION)
VALUES
('a:some text 1 c:some text 2 a:some text 3 c:some text 4 a:some text 5 c:some text 6');
```

--EDITED (previously it was 'a:some_text_1 c:some_text_2 a:some_text_3 c:some_text_4 a:some_text_5 c:some_text_6')

Desired output as two separate fields:

```
CONV_AGENT                              CONV_CUSTOMER
some text 1 ,some text 3, some text 5   some text 2 ,some text 4, some text 6
```

Comment: Is each conversation terminated by single space character? Or ask differently: Is it possible to have conversion like `'a:some text  c:some other text a:ore_text`?

Comment: In my opinion (which doesn't have to be correct), your current situation is *worse* and you're  making it *bad*. Data model isn't correctly set. EVERY "some text" should be stored in its own column, with another column(s) indicating who said that, possibly when, and which conversation it was related to.

Comment: Wernfried Domscheit, yes you are correct! Thanks for this. I have updated the question.

Comment: Littlefoot, as I understand you are suggesting a tidier format which makes sense. I will consider this for the future manipulations of this work. For now I am only interested in words, therefore I simply ignored other things (timing, owner etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove the sub-strings which do not have the correct prefix:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f2f56/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEXT_RECORDS (
    CONVERSATION CLOB
    );

INSERT INTO TEXT_RECORDS(CONVERSATION)
SELECT 'a:some_text_1 c:some_text_2 a:some_text_3 c:some_text_4 a:some_text_5 c:some_text_6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a:some_text_1 a:some_text_2 a:some_text_3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c:some_text_1 a:some_text_2 a:some_text_3 c:some_text_4' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           REGEXP_REPLACE(
             conversation,
             '.*?(a:(\S+))?(\s|$)',  -- Find each word starting with "a:"
             '\2, '                  -- replace with just that part without prefix
           ),
           '(, ){2,}', -- Replace multiple delimiters
           ', '        -- With a single delimiter
         ),
         '^, |, $'     -- Remove leading and trailing delimiters
       ) AS conv_agent,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           REGEXP_REPLACE(
             conversation,
             '.*?(c:(\S+))?(\s|$)',  -- Find each word starting with "c:"
             '\2, '                  -- replace with just that part without prefix
           ),
           '(, ){2,}', -- Replace multiple delimiters
           ', '        -- With a single delimiter
         ),
         '^, |, $'     -- Remove leading and trailing delimiters
       ) AS conv_customer
FROM   text_records
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f2f56/1/0)**:

```
|                            CONV_AGENT |                         CONV_CUSTOMER |
|---------------------------------------|---------------------------------------|
| some_text_1, some_text_3, some_text_5 | some_text_2, some_text_4, some_text_6 |
| some_text_1, some_text_2, some_text_3 |                                       |
|              some_text_2, some_text_3 |              some_text_1, some_text_4 |
```

**Updated - Spaces in conversation sentences**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ff59a/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEXT_RECORDS (
    CONVERSATION CLOB
    );

INSERT INTO TEXT_RECORDS(CONVERSATION)
SELECT 'a:some text 1 c:some text 2 a:some text 3 c:some text 4 a:some text 5 c:some text 6' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a:some text 1 a:some text 2 a:some text 3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c:some text 1 a:some text 2 a:some text 3 c:some text 4' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           REGEXP_REPLACE(
             conversation,
             '.*?(a:([^:]*))?(\s|$)',
             '\2, '
           ),
           '(, ){2,}',
           ', '
         ),
         '^, |, $'
       ) AS conv_agent,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           REGEXP_REPLACE(
             conversation,
             '.*?(c:([^:]*))?(\s|$)',
             '\2, '
           ),
           '(, ){2,}',
           ', '
         ),
         '^, |, $'
       ) AS conv_customer
FROM   text_records
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ff59a/1/0)**:

```
|                            CONV_AGENT |                         CONV_CUSTOMER |
|---------------------------------------|---------------------------------------|
| some text 1, some text 3, some text 5 | some text 2, some text 4, some text 6 |
| some text 1, some text 2, some text 3 |                                       |
|              some text 2, some text 3 |              some text 1, some text 4 |
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply. It worked on real data except for one thing. Using your code above, it separates each word using comma. But what I need is separating each part of conversation using comma. This was my mistake that the original data format is actually like "some text 1 " instead of "some_text_1 ". And Could you update it accordingly? Sorry for causing extra work.

Comment: @kzmlbyrk Updated

Answer (score 0):

You can create two functions, one that get the agent conversation and the other is for customer conversation, see below function to get for agent conversation.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_agent_conv(p_text CLOB) RETURN clob
IS
    v_indx NUMBER := 1;
    v_agent_conv CLOB;
    v_occur NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    LOOP
        v_occur := v_occur + 1;
        v_indx := DBMS_LOB.INSTR(p_text, 'a:', 1, v_occur);
        v_agent_conv := v_agent_conv||', '||SUBSTR(p_text, v_indx+2, (DBMS_LOB.INSTR(p_text, 'c:', 1, v_occur)-4)-(v_indx-1));
    EXIT WHEN v_indx = 0;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN TRIM(', ' FROM v_agent_conv);
END;
/


SELECT GET_AGENT_CONV(conversation) agent_conversation
  FROM text_records;


AGENT_CONVERSATION                                                             
-------------------------------------
some_text_1, some_text_3, some_text_5
```